# create file and assign permissions

Tags: c, posix, file-permissions

It seems as though whatever I put as PERMS the file created has the same permissions - rwx r-x r-x

I tried 755 and 777 and the permissions just stay the same.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#define PERMS 0777

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int createDescriptor;
    char fileName[15]="Filename.txt";

    if ((createDescriptor = creat(fileName, PERMS )) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error creating %s", fileName);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((close(createDescriptor))==-1)
    {
        write(2, "Error closing file.\n", 19);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Turbo C++ IDE?

Answer (score 5):

I think you might need to change the umask before calling `creat`:

```
umask(0000);
```

See `man 2 umask`. The default umask is often 0022 which would exactly make the difference between 0777 and 0755 vanish.

Comment: It works now but not only on newly created files. O_CREAT should overwrite a file if it exists. The permissions stay the same in this case.

Comment: Correct, that's just how it works. You'll need to use `chmod` (or `fchmod`) in that case.

Comment: Could you please explain why it "inherits" the file permissions of the previous file of the same name which has been overwritten? I know there is a structure that contains among other things the mode of the file. Is it that the file permissions in this structure do not change if a file is being overwritten? Or is there a different reason?

Comment: The file is not deleted and recreated; rather, it's just truncated and retains the same inode. From the man page: `creat() is equivalent to open() with flags equal to O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod` function. For more detais just right click in the `IDE` and type `chmod`.

**NAME**:

`chmod` - change mode of a file

**SYNOPSIS:**

```
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

**DESCRIPTION**:

**The chmod()** function shall change `S_ISUID, S_ISGID, [XSI]   S_ISVTX,`  and the file permission bits of the file named by the pathname pointed to by the path argument to the corresponding bits in the mode argument. The application shall ensure that the effective user ID of the process matches the owner of the file or the process has appropriate privileges in order to do this.

`S_ISUID, S_ISGID, [XSI]   S_ISVTX,`  and the file permission bits are described in `<sys/stat.h>.`

If the calling process does not have appropriate privileges, and if the group ID of the file does not match the effective group ID or one of the supplementary group IDs and if the file is a regular file, bit `S_ISGID` (set-group-ID on execution) in the file's mode shall be cleared upon successful return from chmod().

Additional implementation-defined restrictions may cause the `S_ISUID and S_ISGID` bits in mode to be ignored.

The effect on file descriptors for files open at the time of a call to chmod() is implementation-defined.

Upon successful completion, chmod() shall mark for update the st_ctime field of the file.

**RETURN VALUE**:

Upon successful completion, `0` shall be returned; otherwise, `-1` shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error. If `-1` is returned, no change to the file mode occurs.
 More information can be found at [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chmod.html) link.